# I would like to understand the reason behind closing this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, not-a-real-question

Below SO question has been closed as `not a real question`.

[How to fix the Script Task code that downloads ticker price files from Yahoo and inserts into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797886/how-to-fix-the-script-task-code-that-downloads-ticker-price-files-from-yahoo-and)

I believe that this question is related to [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis) even though it is tagged under multiple other things. I understand what the OP is asking for. I don't think any of the users who voted to close this question has been actively involved under [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis)

I would like to understand:

1. Why was this question closed as `not a real question` when OP has provided enough context of what he is trying to do?
2. I assume that question will eventually be deleted because the question has been `closed`. What happens to my answer? I have put enough effort so that answer is useful for people trying to learn SSIS and not just for OP. Yes, I am little disappointed that all my effort to contribute something to [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis) is going to waste.

I appreciate your time to explain things to me.

Comment: The whole question seems to be "It does not work and I don't know why".

Comment: Holy crepes that's a long answer.

Comment: Waffles @J.Steen. Holy waffles.

Comment: @Bart Oh, right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why was this question closed as not a real question when OP has provided enough context of what he is trying to do?

The entire question essentially is: "It does not work and I don't know why".
That makes it come pretty close to a "Debug this for me" request. And that might have caused some of the users to vote to close. We're not a debugging service after all.

Sure, based on the content some users might actually be able to do the debugging. They might be able to get the OP's problems resolved. But that does not make the question a good one.

> I assume that question will eventually be deleted because the question has been closed. What happens to my answer?

No, the question will not necessarily be deleted. Closure is just that: closure. It does not mean the question will be deleted. It might be, if it gather such votes. But especially if there are significantly upvoted answers, this is less likely to happen.

I can't guarantee that it won't be deleted however. And if it does get deleted, the answers will go with it. After all, answers need a question.

If anything, kindly request from the OP that he improves his question, so it can be reopened again. If you worry about the future of the answers, focus on the improvement of the question.

Comment: @Siva If anything, don't answer questions which are not clearly stated. Or signal to the OP that he might want to more clearly state his question. If the OP does not put in the effort to ask a question which might stand the test of time, why would you put in the significant effort to find out what it is he's asking and write an answer to it? The quality of a question is of prime importance.

Comment: @Siva Wow...you went above and beyond. You're an awesome user. Perhaps even a bit too awesome. ;)

Comment: Too awesome is apt. You risk 'wasting your time' everytime you post such a verbose answer for a brand new user with no reputation. The vast majority of 0-rep users come to StackOverflow to leech or vampire... and are automatically treated with a certain amount of hostility and suspicion. Call it hazing - right or wrong, it happens. Expect this type of scrutiny when answering 0-rep questions.

Comment: @Siva Well you're obviously unhappy with something because you posted this question here. My point is that you run the risk of 'quick closures' and other unfairness when you answer 0rep questions. That doesn't make it right but it's something you have to deal with.

Comment: @MikeB - Remember that questions and answers aren't just of value for the original person asking, but for many visitors to come. You aren't at all wasting your time in helping new users, or even less responsive older ones. Some of the answers I'm most proud of have come to poorly asked questions by newer users.

Comment: @BradLarson I understand that and I don't mean to discount those efforts at all. But if reputation is the 'reward' for encouraging good contributions then you have to understand garnering reputation from a new user's question is more difficult than doing so with an established one. I'm speaking towards the reality of the situation and not the utopian theory. Think about it.. a new user might not even know how to accept an answer (or care at all), they might not understand the rules, or they might hold you for ransom while they ask additional questions.

Comment: If that gives you a warm and fuzzy feeling then great- But if you want to be fairly and somewhat-consistently rewarded (also recognized) for the time and effort spent on your content then I'd advise understanding the risks of new users. I'm not advocating blacklisting new users, just accepting the fact that there's additional risks and overhead to new users (this entire meta-post).

Comment: @MikeB - A single user can only give you one upvote and an acceptance vote. Others can give you far more than that in the long term. For example, this user never returned after asking this question, but I've since received 89 votes for my not-accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path/1143095#1143095 . If reputation is your goal, good answers are always wise investments.

Comment: @all this is all very interesting, but if you want to keep discussing this, could you take it to chat or somewhere else than my inbox?